# javascript local sign and sendRawTransaction to remote node

Tags: transactions, javascript, myetherwallet, raw-transaction

In order to use Web3 provided by [MyEtherAPI](https://www.myetherapi.com/), I need to locally sign a transaction, since myetherapi supports only `eth_sendRawTransaction`.

I found a good source to do so on [github](https://github.com/SilentCicero/ethereumjs-accounts), unfortunately it is inactive since 2 years ago. Any idea if there is an active project serving the same purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ethereumjs-tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx) is what you need.

Javascript is extremely popular amongst the Ethereum dev community.

Answer (score 0):

if you can live with a beta version of web3 there is a transparent way to do this with https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3-local-signing-provider

It allows you to set a private key and the library will complete missing transaction object fields (like gas price and gas), sign it locally and send it to the specified provider. It is as seamless as using a local node with an unlocked account.

It is all documented in the Readme of the package